# How can I create a SQLite3 database file using a SQL command file?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a file which contains some SQL commands, something that looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name`;
USE `db_name`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `f_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `f_name`, `l_name`, `company_name`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I'd like to use these commands to create an SQLite3 database file in order to use it easily with Python.

How do I do that on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That isn't quite an SQL file, that contains a bunch of MySQL-specific stuff some of which SQLite will accept and some it won't. We'll start at the top.

You don't need `create database` or `use` with SQLite. If you want to create a database just name it when you run `sqlite3` from the command line:

```
$ sqlite3 db_name.sqlt < your_sql.sql
```

If `db_name.sqlt` exists then it will be used, if it doesn't exist then it will be created. So `create database` and `use` are implied by how you run `sqlite3`. You might need to use a different extension depending on what Python wants to see.

The backticks for quoting are a MySQLism, double quotes are the standard quoting mechanism for identifiers. Lucky for you, SQLite will accept them so you can leave them alone.

SQLite won't know what `int(10) unsigned` means, you'll have to remove the `unsigned` before SQLite will accept it. SQLite also won't know what `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` means so you'll have to remove that as well.

You'll probably run into other things that MySQL is happy with but SQLite is not. You'll have to try it and fix it and try it and fix it until it works. Or try to find a tool that can translate between databases for you, I always do these sorts of things by hand or using one-off scripts so I don't know of any tools that can help you.

Comment: Followed your instructions, getting the following: Error: near line 1: near "INSERT": syntax error. Funny thing, there is no "INSERT" near line 1...

Comment: And say I want to use MySQL instead of Sqlite3. How do I execute these commands? @mu-is-too-short

Comment: What is the whole error message? Just because it complains about line one doesn't mean that it is line one of the file. If you wanted to use MySQL you'd feed that stuff to `mysql`.

Comment: I'm running this command: $ cat commands.sql | sqlite3 db_name.db    this is after applying the changes that you mentioned. The error message is exactly what I'm getting, no more, no less. @mu-is-too-short

Comment: I can't help you if I don't know what the INSERT looks like.

Comment: I understand. Anyway, I got an answer, even though I used MySQL eventually as you suggested. Thanks a bunch. @mu-is-too-short

Answer (score 1):

Basically above commands are for mysql or other database (most of these have to be tweaked in order to work with sqlite. Sqlite stores database in the form of file. Basically when you start sqlite it will create a file (if not present). You can create or open a database by typing

```
sqlite3 db
```

on command line. This statement create or open database named "db"