# SQLite create database for Windows WPF Desktop

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a WPF Desktop application which I want to connect to a SQLite database.
I've read this tutorial about [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).
I've installed it using NuGet.

When I start my application I want to check if the db file exists and if not create it, but sqlite-net doesn't have a CreateDatabase option. It looks like it assumes the file is pre-created.

I've also installed System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64) using NuGet, but I still can't find a method to create a database through C# code.

Can anybody give me some pointers so I can continue?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a SQLite3 database file using a SQL command file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005731/how-can-i-create-a-sqlite3-database-file-using-a-sql-command-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqlite-net creates the database file for you when you call the `CreateTable` method (and it doesn't already exist). Take a look at the [getting started guide](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/GettingStarted) for a full example:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection("mydatabase.db");
db.CreateTable<Person>();
```

Comment: You're right it does. I was playing with the async methods and it seems those are not creating the db file if it doesn't exist. I switched to the SQLiteConnection version and now it works. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure to await the result of the async methods - they should create the database as well.