# Oracle database - offline

Tags: database, oracle, copy, offline

I want to make subsets of a remote Oracle database available for offline use. The Oracle database makes heavy use of Procedures, Functions and Triggers and I need this functionality to be available within the local copy. Transitioning to a db management system better at offline db management (e.g. Sqlite or MySql) would involve a large scope of changes.

In a nutshell, the workflow I need to create is something like:

- user decides to copy data accessible to him into an offline storage
- a download process is triggered to create this local copy
- the user can work offline using his local database

There is no intention to enable committing local changes to the remote host.

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow,

That is a loaded question.  I can think of multiple ways to do this.

You can use **UTL_FILE** and **DBMS_METADATA** to create all you need to follow the procedures of this question:  [How can I create a SQLite3 database file using a SQL command file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005731/how-can-i-create-a-sqlite3-database-file-using-a-sql-command-file)

You can use **UTL_FILE** to create **CSV** data and use other methods to import the data.

You can use **DBMS_LOB** to manually create a "**CREATE DATABASE**" script for **SqlLite3** or **MySql** and use some external method to get the data (ORDS for example)

But if you need to create the DB from scratch (opposed to deleting and inserting) then you need to use **DBMS_METADATA** and some script to save the data.

For example Ask Toms: [Create Insert statements dynamically](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:759825200346294209)

Last,  set up Oracle XE on the users machine, install an SQL client like SQL Developer from Oracle (free) and use **EXP** or **DataPump** to create exports to automatically import to the clients machine.

Regards
Oli

Comment: Thanks a lot for the bulk of useful info. As I said, migrating to sqlite or mysql is not really an option. A large set of the database is useless without procedures and functions. I looked into DataPump a little. This seems to be getting to the core of what I am looking for. 

As far as I understand, it can export and import any subset of tables, functions, procedures, sequences etc. from an oracle db, right?

Comment: Yah right. Data pump can use sql to export a subset. I use it to export subset of data for different companies using the same system.